# Is there any way to lock rows in MySQL Database using Java Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, locking

I am locking one row from a table using PESSIMISTIC_WRITE in MySQL .

However when I execute 'select' statement using MySQL Workbench that particular row is still visible.

Is there any way not to show-up this row when I use 'select' statement.  Although I am not able to update that locked row, which means PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock is working correctly.

Service Layer

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = {Exception.class})
    public List<Employee> getEmployeeList()
    {
        return employeeDAO.getEmploeeList();
    }
```

Dao Layer

```
@Override
    public List<Employee> getEmploeeList() {
        List<Employee> employeeList = null;
        this.session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        String myQry = "from Employee";

        employeeList = session.createQuery(myQry, Employee.class)
                .setMaxResults(1)
                .setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
                .getResultList();

        Employee e = employeeList.get(0);


        return employeeList;
    }
```

The entire code is available at https://github.com/vishy-wisy/Java/tree/main/LockingDemo

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Why exactly do you expect a row lock to cause it to become invisible?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- , Thanks for your reply . I believe that's what pessimistic locking will do . Am I missing something.

Comment: Recent versions of MySQL have finally implemented MVCC. Try (in Workbench) starting a transaction, reading the row, updating it in Java, and then committing the transaction in Workbench so there's a conflict.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- But I want to implement a solution where  if one Java process has selected one row from a table for processing  then another Java process should not pick up the same row .  My table contains millions of rows . I want to process the table in parallel .